# Angular template not updating

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

In my controller:

```
$scope.deleteUser = function(user){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/users/" + user.id.toString(),
            method: "DELETE",
            success: function(result){
                $scope.users = result["users"];
                alertify.success("done");
            },
            error: function () {
                alertify.error("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
```

when I clicked in delete button user successfully removed in the server. In `success` function `result["users"]` object contains one less users. But in template

`%tr{"ng-repeat" => "user in showedUsers | filter: fio_filter"}`

row count not lessen. But when I again clicked on delete button row is removed! why this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS with Ajax Form submission needing to click twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810690/angularjs-with-ajax-form-submission-needing-to-click-twice)

Comment: Use `$http`. There's little reason to use jQuery's `$.ajax` in an AngularJS application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line after your `$scope.users = result["users"];`

```
$scope.users = result["users"];
$scope.$apply();
```

Or, do this

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.users = result["users"];
});
```

Please see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33810890/2405040 for detailed explanation. It is the exact same problem.